# How to store any metadata in google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

How to store any metadata in google sheets for every sheet? I found an article in developers.google.com, but it is for developers only, using API. I want to read/write through appscript coding. Anyway to do this? Actually I want to store some metadata otherthan sheet data, like author:David in a sheet that should not be in the sheet.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `any metadata in google sheets for every sheet`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected value? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike metadata is just some extra data, like LastEditedBy:David, RunScipt:false, ShowExtraColumns:true. The metadata is nothing but a kind of user settings, we use in any app. These data are not part of the sheet's data, it may be sales invoices, purchase bills or anything, we can't store the meta-data inside the sheet data. Though we can store the metadata in a separate sheet, I would like to know if there is any such option available in that corresponding sheet itself.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `metadata is just some extra data, like LastEditedBy:David, RunScipt:false, ShowExtraColumns:true.`, those are the developer metadata? If my understanding is correct, how did you put the values? And, I cannot understand `any such option available in that corresponding sheet itself`. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?

Comment: @Tanaike that's what my question is all about

Comment: About `@Tanaike that's what my question is all about`, thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: @Tanaike hi, there is no issue in your English, We all understand, eventhough an user uses poor English, Forget about that, otherwise, Stackoverflow will move our chats to discussion page. :)

Comment: `... any such option available in that corresponding sheet itself. Can I ask you about the detail of your expected result?` This is what was requested. Language is not an issue. Your reply of `that's what my question is all about` misses the point. You are asked to be specific in terms of your expected outcome. You might ask "why is this necessary?" - it is because `in that corresponding sheet itself` is vague and ambiguous; because there may be many ways (or, indeed, no ways) to record the data that you wish to capture and store; because there may be workarounds to your preferred outcomes.

Comment: @Tedinoz ok, think of a dictionary array with key:value pairs. I want to add RunScipt:false (as key:value). so, the expected is: If I query using 'RunScipt' parameter, it should return me 'false'. I wish, I should be able store these like key:value pairs, in a/every sheet. i.e, the scope should be sheet level, not workbook level. Am I clear now?

Comment: `the scope should be sheet level, not workbook level. Am I clear now?` No